# pentaho kettle cannot connect to cloudera cdh4 HDFS

Tags: hadoop, connection, hdfs, kettle

I am using pentaho data integration tool (Kettle PDI 5.0) and Cloudera CDH4 (ver 4.6) virtualbox singlenode version.

I am trying to run the tutorial [Loading Data into HDFS](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/BAD/Loading+Data+into+HDFS).

But the problem is that I cannot connect to the CDH4 HDFS:
Kettle shows me the error that it cannot connect to HDFS.

I have configured the active.hadoop.configuration to cdh42 and I am running the spoon.bat file from windows 8.1

Kindly provide help if anyone knows how to setup the connection.

Answer (score 0):

To configure connection to Hadoop you need to provide correct configuration files in */plugins/pentaho-big-data-plugin/hadoop-configurations/YOUR_CONF/*. You should at least provide **core-site.xml**.

Then you should edit **plugin.properties** in */plugins/pentaho-big-data-plugin/* and set `active.hadoop.configuration=YOUR_CONF`.

I didn't mentioned *YOUR_CONF* for no reason: it is most likely that CDH 4.2 and 4.6 are not compatible! So you have to create your own configuration dir and provide libraries for it. Most of them come from hadoop and its' components lib folders and others are provided by pentaho like **pentaho-hadoop-shims-hadoop-*.jar**.

Also, consider reading [Hadoop Configurations](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/BAD/Hadoop+Configurations).

Answer (score 0):

So colleague, many times the lack of connection to the directory can be related to the user. when using haddop with pentaho because it is necessary that the user who runs the pentaho is the same user who has the hadoop cores.

for example if you have a user called jluciano on hadoop you need to check a user on the system who uses the same name and then run the process in pentaho, so the accesses to the directory will roll :).

Test it there and anything warns you

Another things, try connect with hostname and after with IP